# cp: fts_open: No such file or directory error

Tags: macos, bash, shell-script

I have this script:

```
    #!/bin/sh -x

    /bin/echo "Drag folder into Terminal and hit return ->"
    /usr/bin/read folderLocation

    /bin/cp -R "$folderLocation" /Users/my/Desktop/
```

And it returns:

```
+ /bin/cp -R '' /Users/my/Desktop/
cp: fts_open: No such file or directory
```

Any idea why that is?

Thank you for any insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work, on Debian Gnu/Linux:

```
#!/bin/sh -x

/bin/echo "Drag folder into Terminal and hit return ->"
read folderLocation

eval "cp -R  -t '/home/my/Desktop' $folderLocation"
```

I dropped the path to read (you may not have to (read is a built in of bash, and can't find it in `/usr/bin` or `/bin`)

Important changes are in last line:

- -t option followed by target directory makes cp more robust.
- eval is needed because of quotes put around return value by read.

As for why you get '' (empty string from read). I am guessing it is because the drag and drop is not working, this is not a feature of the shell but of the terminal and file manager. What terminal program are you using?

Comment: I just dropped /usr/bin right before I read this, so thanks for this :) I'm using Terminal.app in OS X, which does support drag-and-drop-to-full-path-display, so I can do it. Thanks for the additional tips!